# What's the best way of dynamically change validation pattern of an input number element in Angular JS 1.x?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to implement an input number element which can accept either a positive integer value or a percentage value. I've added two radio buttons where the user can chose which kind of value he wants to provide.

My question is: How is the best way to implement this validation using Angular 1.x? I created two regex for each case, but I don't know to redefine the pattern tag dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would go about it. Below is pseudo code.

You can create the value on controller which will hold current validation pattern.

**controller**

```
$scope.validationPattern = 'number';
```

Then when selected radio button changes, this validation pattern should be updated:

**html**

```
<input type="radio" value="number" ng-model="validationPattern">
<input type="radio" value="percent" ng-model="validationPattern">
```

Then you can write your custom directive that will add validators to `ngModel`. This custom directive can watch `validationPattern` and remove the previous validator and add new one on change.

```
app.directive('regexValidator', function (){ 
   return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
          $scope.$watch('validationPattern', function() {
             // remove previous regex pattern
             ngModel.$validators.splice()

             // add new regex pattern
             ngModel.$validators.push()
          });
```